# Зависает screen после переключения на другое окно, либо после разблокировки экрана

Tags: debian, ssh, gnu-screen

Терминал. В нём запущена сессия screen по ssh. Всё работает хорошо. Однако после того, как переключиться на другое окно в системе (Debian 8), а затем вернуться через какое-то время, то screen перестаёт реагировать на клавиатуру и мышь. Соответственно такая же ситуация происходит после разблокировки экрана.

С чем это может быть связано и как это можно починить?

Comment: Стук какой-то подземный. За 10+ лет такого не видел. А если открыть другую сессию и оттуда screen -x - тоже висит?

Comment: @gbg нет, с -x всё работает как надо.

Comment: так это просто ssh зависает или отваливается, делов-то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прозреваю, что из-за неактивности отваливается ssh.

## Проверить просто

Запустить какой-нибудь `ping 127.0.0.1` и уйти в другое окно. Если по возвращению пинг будет бежать - это точно отвал по неактивности.

## Как лечить

Накрутить в `sshd_config` вот эту парочку:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

Время задается в секундах. Первый просто заставит `ssh` слать тестовые пакеты-пинги, второй задает частоту.

Comment: С ping Вы угадали, а вот "лечение" не сработало.

Comment: @edem, а провайдер у вас часом не Йота? или любой другой 3G/4G?

Comment: Нет, обычное оптоволокно. P.S. Насколько помню, раньше, при падении ssh выдавалось "screen is terminating" без зависания экрана, но вот точно сказать не могу за давностью лет и проблемы.

Comment: Странно, но на данный момент всё работает как надо, связываю это с тем, что настройки ssh в прошлый раз не применились, возможно забыл перезапустить после добавления их.